# Al intentar obtener información de una relación Many To Many con Spring Boot, aparece la referencia de memoria

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

Estoy armando un proyecto y tengo un problema: ya que tengo una relación muchos a muchos que quiero desplegar en html con Thymeleaf, pero al momento de desplegar la información, me aparece una referencia de memoria y como tal no hay un campo donde se pueda acceder.

HTML donde quiero mostrar esa información

```html
<tbody>
<tr th:each="evento: ${event}">
    <td th:text="${evento.lista}">Nombre del Evento</td>
    <td th:text="${evento.date}">Fecha del Evento</td>
    <td th:text="${evento.id_validacion.name}">Validacion 
    <td th:text="${evento.horas}">Horas</td> 
    <td th:text="${evento.semestre_actual_id.nombre}">Semestre Actua</td>
    <td th:text="${evento.id_credito.nombre_evento}">Tipo de evento</td> 
</tr>
</tbody>
```

La información que quiero mostrar es la de `evento.lista` pero ahí es donde me aparece la referencia de memoria.

Entidad *estudiante* (que es donde estoy tratando de obtener los datos para mostrarlos en la vista)

```
public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "apellido_paterno", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String apellido_paterno;
@Column(name = "apellido_materno", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String apellido_materno;
@Column(name = "matricula", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String matricula;
@Column(name = "correo", nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
private String email;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_grupo")
private Grupos id_grupo;

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="lista")
private Set<Events> eventos = new HashSet<>();

public Student() {

}
```

Y la entidad de *Eventos* donde la idea es mostrar una lista de estudiantes a través del evento:

```
public class Events {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String name;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false, length = 50)
private Date date;

@JoinColumn(name = "id_validacion")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Validacion.class)
private Validacion id_validacion;

@JoinColumn(name = "id_plan_estudios")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = PlanEstudios.class)
private PlanEstudios id_plan_estudios;

@JoinColumn(name = "semestre_actual_id")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = SemestreActual.class)
private SemestreActual semestre_actual_id;

@JoinColumn(name = "tipo_evento_id")
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Credito.class)
private Credito id_credito;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "eventos_has_estudiantes", schema = "registro_credito",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "eventos_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "estudiantes_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Student> lista = new HashSet<>();

@Column(name = "horas", nullable = false, length = 50)
private int horas;
```

Comparto el controlador para poder obtener esa vista junto con sus variables:

```
@GetMapping("/event/lista/{id}")
public String listaEvent(@PathVariable Long id, Model modl) {
    List<Student> estudiantes = servicioEstudiante.getstudents();
    modl.addAttribute("event", service.getEventById(id));
    modl.addAttribute("estudiantes", estudiantes);
    return "listaEvent";
}
```

Cuento con sus correspondientes Getters y Setters; así mismo les muestro la relación que tengo: quiero obtener al menos el id, y anexo la imagen de la referencia de memoria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como es tu controller para mostrar los datos en la vista? cual y cómo es el error que te sale? danos más detalles.

Comment: Como tal no hay un error desplegado en la consola al momento de traer los datos